# Disabled HTML button is showing on top of sticky table header, active buttons are not

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am developing a website using bootstrap 5 as my framework.
My problem is as stated in the title. While scrolling down on my page and keeping the table header stuck to the top the disabled button will show overtop of the header.

I have tried to use the disabled property and class name (for bootstrap)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped align-middle mx-auto">
  <thead>
    <tr style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: white;">
      <th scope="col" style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: white;">Date</th>
      <th scope="col" style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: white;">Agenda</th>
      <th scope="col" style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: white;">Meeting Minutes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 19th<br><small class="text-muted"> Budget Meeting Workshop <u>6:00pm</u></small></th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwagnd.pdf')">View</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="setSrc('brdmtgs/2019b/marbwmtg/marbwmin.pdf')">View</button></td>
    </tr>
```

````
```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="afterme">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Meeting Information</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="download_file()">Download</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To not have this happen with another element other than the button another solution is to get the top header bar to always be above the table.

So instead of bringing the disabled button down one level, bring the top bar up one level:

```
.table > thead {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

(You can also add a class to your `<thead>` Element and target the element directly, whatver is easiest for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `css`,

```css
.btn-primary:disabled {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked as well as the other solution!